# Retrieving the image using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, croppie

I am beginner in `PHP` and `Ajax query`. I am trying to upload an `profile image` using `croppie.js plugin`. When I am uploading the `image`, the image would be saved like `1580192100.png`. But my problem is there is an impossible to `retrieve the image` according to the `userid`.

Here is the code which I tried. `profilepic.php` page

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once "../auth/dbconnection.php";

if (isset($_POST['image'])) {

    $croped_image = $_POST['image'];
    list($type, $croped_image) = explode(';', $croped_image);
    list(, $croped_image)      = explode(',', $croped_image);
    $croped_image = base64_decode($croped_image);
    $image_name = time().'.png';


 // Valid file extensions
 $allowTypes = array( 'bmp', 'jpg', 'png', 'jpeg' , 'JPG');

// if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET image = ? WHERE user_id= ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("si", $image_name, $_SESSION['user_id']);
    $stmt->execute();
    if($stmt->affected_rows === 0);


      file_put_contents('blog/'.$image_name, $croped_image);
    echo 'Cropped image uploaded successfully.';




    }else{

        echo "ERROR: Could not prepare query: $stmt. " . mysqli_error($conn);

    }

    $stmt->close();
//    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);



?>
```

The `php fetch` code would be;

```
<?php

require_once 'auth/dbconnection.php';
$sql="SELECT image FROM users WHERE user_id= '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
        if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

$out= '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image']).'" alt="">';
echo $out;

        }
    }
}
?>
```

[image]

I don't know where I went t wrong. Please help me.

Comment: plese clarify the problem. Do you wish to save the image using the `$userid` rather than simply the time?

Comment: @RamRaider Problem in retrieving the `image`

Comment: @NasikThaheed Did you get the value in `$_SESSION['user_id']` and `$row['image']` ?. Also you have missed the path of the image.

Comment: @DroidDev Sure. I get the value..

Comment: @NasikThaheed can you check in the browser for the image eg. `http://example.com/images/1580196780.png` with the full path.

Comment: @DroidDev I follow a tutorial. in php code there is a code segement like   `$croped_image = base64_decode($croped_image);`. But in database it shows like. `1580196780.png`. Is it `decoded ????`

Comment: The image should not have to base64 encoded or decoded. The png file should be saved on the server. It appears you are saving the filename in the table, which is the right way to do it. But, you're getting the filename by using a timestamp rather than the actual filename the file is saved under (ie  `$image_name = time().'.png';`). You should either get the real filename, or at least change the name of the file to the one you want it to be.

Comment: @NasikThaheed you need to save the cropped `$croped_image` in the db, because you only saving the current time. That is not a valid image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `update` statement sets the image name in the database rather than any base64 encoded data ( better to save just the name otherwise the table will become huge ) so when you try to display the image you need to read the image data. I modified the above to use a `prepared statement`

```
<?php
    if( !empty( $_SESSION['user_id'] ) ){

        require_once 'auth/dbconnection.php';


        $sql='select `image` from `users` where `user_id`=?';
        $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bind_param( 's',$_SESSION['user_id'] );

        # determine the correct path for the image
        $filepath=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/profile/blog/';

        $res=$stmt->execute();
        if( $res ){
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result($filename);

            while( $stmt->fetch() ){
                /* 
                    You store the filename ( possibly path too ) 
                    so you need to read the file to find it's
                    raw data which you will use as image source.
                    Use the filepath to find the image!!
                */
                printf(
                    '<img src="data:image/png;base64, %s" alt="" />',
                    base64_encode( file_get_contents( $filepath . $filename ) )
                );      
            }
            $stmt->free_result();
            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I inserted this code. the error shows like `Warning:file_get_contents(1580196780.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Hospital\adminpanel\edit-profile.php on line 412`. My containing folder is `profile/blog/`

Comment: ok - It was not clear what the path was or whether that was stored in the db or if it was just the name. Prefix the filename with the correct path before `file_get_contents`

Comment: Great stuff, glad it helped.